# While deleting a record I am getting Ignore ActiveRecord Not found with SomeModel id 1121

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def perform(args = {})
      id = args[:id]
      SomeModel.where(id: id).find_each(batch_size: 50) do |a|
          a.destroy 
      end
end
```

But the object of the model is getting deleted. So, after deletion why am I getting:

> Ignore Active record not found with SomeModel id 1121

Comment: "Ignore" is part of the error message? I am only aware of errors like "ActiveRecord Not Found" (without "Ignore")

Comment: Ignore ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find SomeModel with id=1121 >, 1

Comment: this is from logs

Comment: the records are getting deleted from the DB. but i am not sure why getting this

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace? Is `a.destroy` the original cause of the exception? And  is `SomeModel` one of the `a` record itself? Because just in case you may have some `after_destroy`, callbacks that's trying to destroy some associated record (that no longer exists)

Comment: Also, can you try adding `a.reload` just above `a.destroy`? Because if that raises an error, then that means that one of the `a` in the array has already been destroyed, and why you can't destroy something that's already destroyed.

Comment: a.destroy is not giving any exception. yes SomeModel is a record in itself.

Comment: "`a.destroy` is not giving any exception", you said? Then that means it's somewhere else where the error is being raised? Please include that related code in your post.

Comment: Ohh `a.destroy` is not giving any exception, but is writing to logs? Was that what you meant? If so, then in that log file can you show the full stacktrace? (the stacktrace should be there by default, unless it's configured not to be written to logs)

Comment: yes a.destroy is not giving exception i have checked that myself. but it is writing in logs. And object is getting deleted from the record i have checked that. and for your information it is a worker file

Comment: Yes, can you show the stacktrace in that worker file? It should be there no?  It would help determining the original line of error. If it's not there, then maybe you or somewhere in your code is rescuing explicitly the error, but then just explicitly printing the error.message in the log (without the stacktrace)

Comment: I am getting that log only ....i have to check config as you said

Comment: Are you in "development" mode or is that log file error in "production"? If you can reproduce the error in "development" mode, can you try running the job synchronously? (say via in `rails console`), you do something like `SomeJob.perform_now(some_args)`? If that doesn't throw an exception, then something is rescuing the error, without reraising it (may be intentionally or a bug).

Comment: thanks bro, i fixed the problem there was some other worker file which trying to find that record after it was deleted(a.destroy)

Comment: No prob. Glad to help :)

Comment: `SomeModel.where(id: id).find_each(batch_size: 50)`!! Man, do you have a model which can have multiple instances with same id?? If not, then why not `SomeModel.where(id: id).first`??

Comment: yes it can have multiple instances.